How do you deal with overflowing items on Fulgora?
On Fulgora your main source for materials is recycling scrap. This results in a mixture of many different items that you need to handle. If you don't handle it your base quickly grinds to a halt because one of the products accumulates and blocks your other processes.
Right now I'm collecting items that didn't get used in chests, but that obviously only delays the inevitable. Especially solid fuel but also ice do accumulate quickly. I have no use for solid fuel at all right now, and ice is not used in sufficient amounts.
My best idea right now would be to simply recycle the overflowing products endlessly until nothing is left. Which does not seem a particularly good way to handle this, so I am wondering if there are any other options?

What is it that you don't like about recycling overflow endlessly?

I have some suggestions:
First, consider what you will eventually  need. For solid fuel specifically, you will end up needing lots of rocket fuel to ship science packs and such to orbit for transfer back to Nauvis. Start stockpiling finished items instead of raw ingredients.
Second, notice that recyclers can accept quality modules. You can cycle away much of your stockpile while skimming for higher quality items. From there, you can either use those to improve your base, or export higher quality science packs. If I am reading the wiki page correctly, higher quality items have 200%, 300%, 400%, or 600% durability. That means each stack of science counts for more, and thus interplanetary shipping is cheaper per science.
Third, you might be able to export relatively higher value scrap to other planets, particularly where it is harder to make those things locally.
Fourth, you could use the fuel and ice specifically for generating steam power in boilers.

This is correct, with the caveat that quality science packs stack separately, and you need a full rocket before automation will send it. In practice, I found that was really not worth the trouble - you could just make more science packs / rockets with that space & power.
However, I had my quality factory on fulgora for space parts, and that was a huge advantage. Quality turrets shoot further, quality asteroid collectors have extra arms that reach further, quality solar panels produce more power in the same footprint, and quality cargo bays store more.

@DanielHeath yes, packs stack separately. No, rockets default to requiring a full stack but you can override that to allow partially filled rockets (or just wait until a full stack is ready for the next trip). Once the filters are set up appropriately, it is barely a problem to feed the quality packs to labs first. We do largely agree on my second point, that making quality stuff for your base (or space ships) is good. I would also tack on personal equipment, like armor, equipment like personal roboports, and personal weapons

Solid fuel + water (ice) runs in a burner for power, but there seems little point when lightning provides so much.
So far, endless recycling is the best approach I've found.

Hi Daniel, welcome to Arqade! Since the OP explicitly states endless recycling is what they do already, I'm not sure this is a helpful answer. This reads more like a comment, but you'll need a little reputation to be able to post those. Please take our [Tour] to familiarize yourself with our site.

@Joachim I think it is helpful. I suspect there is nothing better, so having a confirmation of that has some value. I played a bit more by now and it does look like endless recycling is indeed the intended path

On Nauvis, production is limited by electricity, pollution, and resource availability.
On Fulgora, power is free & nearly unlimited, pollution doesn't exist, and resource patches are huge. Production is primarily limited by your ability to dispose of excess in recyclers.

@DanielHeath yes, but on Fulgora you also face relatively limited building space, pushing you to a different kind of design than on Nauvis.

Recycling really is the most reliable way to go. I know it seems wasteful, but unless you somehow manage things so that your base uses the products of scrap in exactly the right ratios, you're going to need to destroy items to keep the process flowing.
